# Backand - use own db row id as primary key

Tags: backand

Is it possible to specify your own row ID in backand objects? I want to form one-to-one relationsships in database, where I have two objects: userPrivateData and userProfile

I would like to use the id of Backands own internal user object as primary key for both objects. So basically a userId. The reason for this: With REST api you can access single items with GET /1/objects/{name}/{id}

Since I don't know the row id I want to use another unique identiefier as primary key, that I know - my user id.

Is this possible? Maybe I have the concept all wrong, in their docs they talk a lot about one-to-many relationships and stuff, but not about one-to-one relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your JSON model would look something like this.

```
    [
  {
    "name": "items",
    "fields": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "user": {
        "object": "users"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "users",
    "fields": {
      "items": {
        "collection": "items",
        "via": "user"
      },
      "allofuserprivatedata": {
        "collection": "userPrivateDataThings",
        "via": "userId"
      },
      "email": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "firstName": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "lastName": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "userProfile": {
        "object": "userProfile"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "userProfile",
    "fields": {
      "userid": {
        "collection": "users",
        "via": "userProfile"
      },
      "fieldOne": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "fieldTwo": {
        "type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "userPrivateDataThings",
    "fields": {
      "field1": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "field2": {
        "type": "float"
      },
      "userId": {
        "object": "users"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Use a collection when you want 1 to many.
Use an object when you want 1 to 1.

When you do a GET on user with deep:true the nested relationship data will come back in the response.